# Jquery/Javascript to hide/show div in li

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have many div's on a page, like the one below with different information, using the same classes.

```
<div class="one-third">
    <ul class="img-list">
        <a href="#" target="_blank">
            <li>
                <img src="#" alt="" />
                <span class="text-content"><h3 style="color:white" id="one">BRIAN FARGO</h3></span>
                <h5 class="text-content-desc" id="two">CEO, inXile entertainment</h5>
                <a href="https://twitter.com/BrianFargo">
                <img class="speaker-twitter-profile" src="#"></a>
                <div class="info-btn" onClick="swap('one','two')">info</div>
            </li>
        </a>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And a javascript functions is:

```
function swap(one, two) {
    document.getElementById(one).style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById(two).style.display = 'none';
}
```

The problem is, when I click on the "info" button, it effects on all div's, but I need it to only effect on the div which button is clicked.

Like if I click on info of BRIAN FARGO, it should only show/hide/effect BRIAN FARGO'S bio. Not all other speakers.

Comment: You know that IDs must be unique, right?

Comment: I think you need to review your swap() function and make sure that it is only targeting siblings, etc, is there a chance you can include that here?

Comment: Using invalid markup, `<a>` can't be a direct child of `<ul>`

Comment: you means or want to use and tab's components? like this -> http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs

Comment: Also, as blex said, you can't have the same two IDs repeating more than once on the same page.

Comment: You can use the `parentNode` instead of the `document`: http://jsfiddle.net/Lby0we08/

Comment: Please see this link, http://2014.arctic15.com/speakers/ when you click on "Show full bio" it only open the bio of button you click. Not all. My code is doing for all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why is your function named swap() when all it does is changes the display attribute of one element to block (which it already is by default) and changes another elements display to none effectively hiding it.

If you have many divs with the same id, that too could be your problem. Id should be unique for each element

Comment: Yes, I'm putting different id's. And passing that id's in my function. It works. Thanks you!